# Rails, global storage for js variable

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps, geolocation

i get user location via navigator.geolocation. What i need is using user geolocation in my controller for sorting by distance. How to get navigator.geolocation from the controller? Is there some global storage for this kind of javascript object for each user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should send geolocation from javascript to rails via POST/COOKIE.

**jQuery**

```
$(function(){ 
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos){
    $.post('/set_geolocation',{latitude: pos.coords.latitude, longitude: pos.coords.longitude}) 
  });      
});
```

**Rails**

```
# routes.rb
...
post '/set_geolocation' => 'users#set_geolocation'
... 


# users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def set_geolocation
    session[:location] = {:latitude=> params[:latitude], :longitude=> params[:longitude]}
  end
end
```

Or

**jQuery**

```
$(function(){ 
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos){
    document.cookie = document.cookie + '; latitude=pos.coords.latitude; longitude=pos.coords.longitude'
  });      
});
```

**Rails**

# somewhere in controllers
  ...cookie[:latitude]...